# How to Button onclick get selected radiobutton value inside listview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have no ideo that how to get the selected value from radiobutton list, I tried many c# code but still couldn't work. I'm using ASP.NET C#. Help, please.

```
                <ItemTemplate>   
                    <div class="question">        
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' />
                        <br />
                        <img style="padding-left:25px" src="../images/Quiz/<%# Eval("Photo") %>" /><br />
                        <br />Answer:&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelect" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                             <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 2&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Value="3"> 3&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Value="4"> 4</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudhakar's method isn't necessarily wrong, but your ListView is going to have *n* number of rows, and each row will have a copy of your RadioButtonList.  There are a multitude of ways to get the value, but the easiest will probably be something like this:

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach(ListViewDataItem item in listView.Items)
     {
           var rbl = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rblSelect")
           var selectedValue = rbl.SelectedItem.Value;
           var selectedText = rbl.SelectedItem.Text;
           var selectedIndex = rbl.SelectedIndex;
     }
 }
```

My code assumes that your ListView is named 'listView'.  This code is obviously in the click event handler of a button named btnSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
string RadioButtonValue = rblSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: The c# code shows "The name "rblSelect" does not exist in the current context. But my radiobuttonlist id is rblSelect. Is it because the radiobuttonlist is inside the listview table so it couldn't work?

Comment: try with `ListViewName.rblSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();`

Comment: Same. The name "rblSelect" does not exist in the current context.